# Pandas Unable to Read CSV file using pandas, with extra quote char

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have following CSV  with following entries

> "column1"| "column2"| "column3"| "column4"| "column5"
>   "123" | "sometext", "this somedata", "8 inches"", "hello"

The issue comes when i try to read `8 inches"`, i am unable to read the csv using `read_csv()`.

```
Pandas.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), sep="|",
                                      quoting=1,
                                      engine='c', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True,
                                      encoding="utf-8", converters=pandas_config['converters'],skipinitialspace=True,escapechar='\"')
```

Is there a way to handle the quote within the cell.

Comment: What is the error? It's really an issue with the .csv file. I would maybe run a script over the input file to fix the quoting issue. Are there two types of separators (`|` and `,`) as well? Or is the entire entry between the final bar and the end of the line a single column? Can you include the converter you're using?

Comment: @mgrollins: there is only `|` as seperator, the issue is actually with csv file, but this a special case, and i am getting a double quote within the string

Comment: @mgrollins: this is the error `Exception while performing pandas.read_csv operation. error: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 0, pandas config:`

Comment: Can you clean up the input from `obj['Body']` before trying to read it in? Are you sure there are no null characters in the first row prior to the end of the line?

Answer (score 2):

Start from passing appropriate parameters for this case:

1. *sep='[|,]'* - there are **two** separators: a *pipe* char and a *comma*,
   so define them as a *regex*.
2. *skipinitialspace=True* - your source text contains extra spaces (after
   separators), so you should drop them.
3. *engine='python'* - to suppress a warning concerning *Falling back to the
   'python' engine*.

The above options alone allow to call *read_csv* with no error, but the downside
(for now) is that double quotes remain.

To eliminate them, at least from the data rows, another trick is needed:

Define a converter (lambda) function:

```
cnv = lambda txt: txt.replace('"', '')
```

and apply it to all source columns.

In your case you have 5 columns, so to keep the code concise,
you can use a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
{ i: cnv for i in range(5) }
```

So the whole code can be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep='[|,]', skipinitialspace=True,
    engine='python', converters={ i: cnv for i in range(5) })
```

and the result is:

```
  "column1"  "column2"       "column3"  "column4"  "column5"
0      123    sometext   this somedata   8 inches      hello
```

But remember that now all columns are of *string* type, so you should
convert required columns to numbers.
An alternative is to pass second converter for numeric columns,
returning a **number** instead of a string.

To have proper column names (without double quotes), you can pass additional parameters:

- *skiprows=1* - to omit the initial line,
- *names=["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5"]* - to
  define the column list on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the info, lets assume i have proper converter , i am failing for datetime columns

Comment: If your converter for datetime fields fails then most likely the problem is just in this converter. To investigate the issue, call such converter for a few cases of input data, look at the results and correct the converter to return proper results.

Answer (score 0):

We can specify a somewhat complicated separator, read the datas and strip the extra quote chars:

```
# Test data:
text='''"column1"| "column2"| "column3"| "column4"| "column5" 
        "123" | "sometext", "this somedata", "8 inches"", "hello"'''
ff=io.StringIO(text)


df= pd.read_csv(ff,sep=r'"\s*[|,]\s*"',engine="python")
# Make it tidy:
df= df.transform(lambda s: s.str.strip('"'))
df.columns= ["column1"]+list(df.columns[1:-1])+["column5"]
```

The result:

```
  column1   column2        column3   column4 column5
0     123  sometext  this somedata  8 inches   hello
```

Comment: i am getting error for the last column, which in my real case is a date time column, you can say my column5 is of type datetime, i am getting this error `Exception while performing pandas.read_csv operation. error: 'RECORD_CREATED_TIMESTAMP' is not in list`, although i have it my convertor list